# Cancel header macro command

Tags: pdftex

I made two original commands:

```
\newcommand{\headremark}[1]{%
\newpage
\lhead{#1}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

Then I use them in my thesis, like.

```
\begin{abstract}
\pagenumbering{roman}
aaa
\end{abstract}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\headremark{Acknowledgments}
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
aaa
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
```

But "Acknowledgment" is displayed in the header of Contents and Chapter 1.
I guess "headremark" command continues even in the following chapters.
How can I avoid it and display "CONTENTS" or "Chapter 1 INTRODUCTION"?

I attach the compirable minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
            a4paper,
            one side,
            one column,
            titlepage,
            final,
            ]{report}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{framed}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{623.5pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{432.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{25pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headwidth}{432.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\lhead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Dept.}

\newcommand{\headremark}[1]{%
\newpage
\lhead{#1}%
}

\title{AAA}
\author{ \\ \\ \\ \\NAME\\}
\date{Dec 2023}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
\pagenumbering{roman}
aaa
\end{abstract}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\headremark{Acknowledgments}
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
aaa

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a compilable document (minimal working example), it's hard to advise as the best way to do this depends on the class you're using and which packages you're loading to configure headers/footers and chapters. But the way things like chapter titles get into headers in the standard classes is that commands such as `\chapter` set `mark`s and headers use these marks rather than containing hard-coded titles. The documentation for `fancyhdr` has some more details on this. Basically, you don't want to put `Acknowledgements` directly into the header at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added the minimal example that causes my problem.

Comment: Why do you set `pagestyle` to three different values in the preamble?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the contents of headers/footers directly. You don't want to hard code `Acknowledgements` any more than you want to hard code page `3`. Just as you use `\thepage`, use one or some of LaTeX's `mark`s. Admittedly, these are a bit trickier than `\thepage`, but `fancyhdr`'s documentation is a considerable help and there are fewer complexities in a one-sided document, so it should not be too bad.

I strongly recommend considering the use of `geometry` and `titling` (or similar). Setting every dimension by hand is error prone and inflexible. Setting the title with forced new lines borders on barbarism.

```
\documentclass[12pt,
            a4paper,
            one side,
            one column,
            titlepage,
            final,
            ]{report}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% do you have something against geometry?
% this is extremely error prone.
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{10pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{623.5pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{432.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{25pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headwidth}{432.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\plainfootrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[lh]{\leftmark}
\fancyhf[rh]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[rf]{Dept.}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \pagestyle{fancy}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{\typeout{Patching succeeded.}}{\typeout{Patching failed.}}

\title{AAA}
\author{ \\ \\ \\ \\NAME\\}% this is a pretty bad way to do this - consider using the titling package
\date{Dec 2023}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{abstract}
  aaa
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\markboth{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
aaa

\end{document}
```

The above assumes you don't want uppercase headers. If you do, you don't need to redefine `\chaptermark` or patch `\tableofcontents`.

[image: tamer marks in headers]

I assume you are forced to use this style by the usual institutional insanity, so I won't point out typographical deficiencies of which I'm sure you're all too aware already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your answer. Yes, I'm forced to use the institutional format with small modifications. Additional question: Can I use an upper-case header like "CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION"? If I don't use patch command, CONTENTS seems OK but the following chapters are showed with lower-case characters.

Comment: @Sato Comment/remove the `\chaptermark` line, as well as the contents patch. Upper case is default. I did it this way because I wasn't sure which you wanted.